# mongoengine.fields.ImproperlyConfigured: PIL library was not found

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

When I try to import a MongoEngine class which has an ImageField, an error says:

```
mongoengine.fields.ImproperlyConfigured: PIL library was not found
```

My class structure is like this:

```
class TrafficSign(Document):
    name = StringField()
    image = ImageField()
    type = StringField()
    desc = StringField()
    source = StringField()
```

Whats the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install [`Pillow`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.5.3), which provides the `PIL` module. `sudo pip install Pillow` (drop the `sudo` if on Windows) ought to do it.